# File name extraction

Tags: c#

In C#, it is necessary to match the names of the files in the folder with the registered IDs in the database. But the filenames are like this: 0000138_0.jpeg, 0007979_0.png etc.
I need to discard the leading zeros and not get the trailing dash. So like 138 and 7979 in the examples. My code is like this but it doesn't meet my need. What should I do?

```
 public void img()
        {
            List<Product> dbProducts= Db2Context.Product.Where(a => a.Deleted == false).ToList();
            foreach (Product Pro in dbProducts)
            {
                TBL_Product db1Urun = Db1Context.TBL_Product.Where(a => a.ID == ("SKU-")).FirstOrDefault() ?? new TBL_Product();
                var imgs= Db2Context.Product_Picture_Mapping.Where(a => a.PictureId == a.PictureId).FirstOrDefault();


                if (imgs != null)
                {
                    string partialName = imgs.PictureId.ToString();
                    DirectoryInfo hdDirectoryInWhichToSearch = new DirectoryInfo(firstPath);
                    FileInfo[] filesInDir = hdDirectoryInWhichToSearch.GetFiles("*" + partialName + "*_0*");

                    foreach (FileInfo foundFile in filesInDir)
                    {
                        string fullName = foundFile.FullName;
                        secondPath = firstPath + fullName;
                        Db1Product.Image= secondPath;
                    }

                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: *but it doesn't meet my need* Can you elaborate? Is it matching on too many files? Too few? What?

Comment: Your code is doing DB queries inside a loop - that's very inefficient. Think about how this can be done with a set-based approach.

Comment: Yes, there are thousands of files with this name. Well when I solve the problem I implement cluster based

Comment: integer parsing functions will discard leading zeroes. Check that `IndexOf` doesn't fail, but something like `int.Parse(partialName.Substring(0, partialName.IndexOf('_')))` gives `"0007979_0.png" -> 7979`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a regex to match and extract the ID from the file.

Here is a fiddle of the below code: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZCgcG3

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pat = @"^0+(\d+)";
        Regex r = new Regex(pat);
        string[] files = {"000138_0.jpeg", "0007979_0.png", "ignore this file.txt"};

        foreach (var s in files)
        {
            Match m = r.Match(s);
            if (m.Success)
                Console.WriteLine("matched: " + s + " - " + m.Groups[1].Value);
            else
                Console.WriteLine("ignored: " + s);
        }
    }
}
```

and the output:

```
matched: 000138_0.jpeg - 138
matched: 0007979_0.png - 7979
ignored: ignore this file.txt
```